# App is crashing when I click the button - two intents in a button - using Enum

Tags: android, android-intent

I need help with my code. Let me try to explain the problem:
At the first activity I have two fields where I'll set values from an Enum, for this I made a button for each field that basically shows me another activity, calls the value and brings it to the main activity. Still in the first activity I have a button that starts another activity and (at the same time) take all the values from the enum end sends to another activity. The point is, everything is working, but this last button no, when I click it the app crashes. What is happening and how can I solve it?

Here goes the code of the first activity:

```
public class MenuInicial extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int CONSTANTE_BANZO = 1;

Button escolherM;
Button escolherB;
Button next;
TextView campoM;
TextView campoB;
Intent intent1;
Intent intent2;
Intent intentBundle;
Intent intentNext;
Bundle bundle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_inicial);

    intent1 = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Montante.class);

    campoM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fieldM);
    escolherM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseM);

    String perfilM = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameM");

    campoM.setText(perfilM);

    escolherM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });

    intent2 = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Banzo.class);

    campoB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fieldB);
    escolherB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseB);

    escolherB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivityForResult(intent2, CONSTANTE_BANZO);
        }
    });

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
    intentBundle = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, ConferenciaDosDados.class);
    intentNext = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Dados.class);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String perfilM = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameM");
            Float baseMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseM");
            Float alturaMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("alturaM");
            String perfilB = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameB");
            Float baseBz = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseB");
            Float alturaBz = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("alturaB");
            bundle.putString("nomeM",perfilM);
            bundle.putFloat("baseM",baseMt);
            bundle.putFloat("alturaM",alturaMt);
            bundle.putString("nomeB",perfilB);
            bundle.putFloat("baseB",baseBz);
            bundle.putFloat("alturaB",alturaBz);
            intentBundle.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intentBundle);
            startActivity(intentNext);

        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int codigo, int resultado, Intent intent){

    if(codigo == CONSTANTE_BANZO){
        Bundle bundleB = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundleB != null){
            String perfilB = bundleB.getString("nameB");
            campoB.setText(perfilB);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post the ``stacktrace`` of the error

Comment: you are trying to start two activity at same time inside next.setOnClickListener  click

Comment: so what can I do?

Comment: @MateusNogueira "so what can I do?" is that a trick question? heres what you CANT do.... is go to TWO separate activity by clicking on ONE button..... impossible.

Comment: is there any reason why you need to have 2 activities launch at once?

Comment: You can start one activity and pass the values to another by using public static variables. Start whichever activity you want and pass the values by assigning the values to some public static variables and call them using ClassName.VariableName in the activity you need the values. This way you won't call two separate activities at the same time which is the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
    intentBundle = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, ConferenciaDosDados.class);
    intentNext = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Dados.class);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String perfilM = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameM");
            Float baseMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseM");
            Float alturaMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("alturaM");
            String perfilB = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameB");
            Float baseBz = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseB");
            Float alturaBz = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("alturaB");
            bundle.putString("nomeM",perfilM);
            bundle.putFloat("baseM",baseMt);
            bundle.putFloat("alturaM",alturaMt);
            bundle.putString("nomeB",perfilB);
            bundle.putFloat("baseB",baseBz);
            bundle.putFloat("alturaB",alturaBz);
            intentBundle.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intentBundle);
            startActivity(intentNext);

        }
    });
```

Which activity do you want to go to? choose one. When you do, you can get those extras then when you need to goto the other activity, you can put those extras there too.

A better way to do it is to create a model (constructor with setters and getters) and put these in a list. At that point you can loop through the list and take what you need. It all depends on what you are doing though as the list will not be instantiated like intent extras would be.

Or, you can use SharedPref which is similar to a HashMap (which is also similar to the Intent Extras). SharedPref will store the key and value on the phones cache and then you can pull from that when you need it. Again, keep in mind that if the user clears the cache on the app, then it'll delete those shared pref.

Finally, you can also use a database such as Parse Server or Firebase.

Comment: Still not working with the changes I've made:

next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
intentNext = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Dados.class);

      next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Float baseMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseM");
              bundle.putFloat("baseM",baseMt);
              intentNext.putExtras(bundle);
              startActivity(intentNext);

            }
        });
    }

Comment: I believe the reason is because that's not how you handle extras. You pass in extras to another activity for what you want to use. For what it looks like, you're getting extras from one activity and then passing them in into the next. That's not how you do it

Comment: Thank you, I've passed the data using extras (not bundle) and it worked ;)